# Chrome extension that worked on Facebook yesterday doesn't work today

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome extension that inserts a button under Facebook posts. It was inserting the button just fine for months. But today, after making zero updates, it stopped working --- no button appears.

The Chrome logs say:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Error occurred when adding button. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
    at callAttentionToX (content.js:18)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (waitForKeyElements.js:49)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:367)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:202)
    at waitForKeyElements (waitForKeyElements.js:43)
    at content.js:74
```

Here's my code:

```
function callAttentionToX(jNode) {
    var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");

    var button = document.createElement("a");
    button.innerHTML = "Button";

    try {
        var image = uCW[0].children[1].children[2].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
        console.log(image);

        var title = uCW[0].children[1].children[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes[2].value;
        console.log(title);

        var url = uCW[0].children[1].children[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
        console.log(url);

        var stringcheese = String(image);
        console.log(stringcheese);

        window.bar2 = stringcheese;


        if (bar2.startsWith("https://external") 
        ) {
            uCW.append(button);
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error occurred when adding button.", error)
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing it is impossible to say. But most likely the Facebook site changed.

Comment: Basically, I use Javascript to find a div on Facebook and add a button under it. I checked, the div is still there.

Comment: Maybe the children changed then. Because it complains about uCW[0].children[1].children[2] being undefined

Comment: Oh that's a good idea, I'll try that

Comment: Your approach is inherently fragile and it **will** break regularly. There's no way around this though. You'll have to constantly monitor the site, maybe write an automated test.

Comment: And so my watch begins.